# Workbooks.Open (URL) + Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

```
Workbooks.Open ("www.google.com" & ThisWorkbook("Summary").Range("C3") & ".xls")
```

I am trying to open a link that depends on what is posted in a cell. So the document might be named "File1" or "File2" and I would like the user to type that into cell C3 and click a button that downloads that file. The formula I have wont support concatenation with cells. Any other options?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using the following in your code as I guess your syntax is not correct

thisworkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("C3").Value

Comment: did not think about that one...thanks for the post, appreciate the input, will jot it down in my handy-dandy notes (#tryingToVBA)

Comment: Hey Dan, what if I am trying to .NumberFormat this range that I am pasting. I am not succeeding by just adding .NumberFormat to the end of the statement. I would like the format to be "yyyymmdd" if that makes sense

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what your problem is... do you mean that the file name must be completed with a date, formated in yyyymmdd format ? Could you post : - The final value of the URL you try to achieve and the source data that you have ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question by defining the cell path...so i put:

Set userID = Worksheets("Summary").Range("C3")

and in the URL I put

```
Workbooks.Open ("www.google.com" & userID & ".xls")
```